# jruby on rails and jar files

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, jar

How can run an executable jar file through a jruby on rails application?  Where would I include the code to run my jar file?

I have looked all over but have yet to see a defined method for doing this type of thing and I'm also very new to rails.

Comment: What do you mean with 'run a jar file'? It's it an executable jar?

Comment: Yes, sir.  Will edit to include that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you can do 3 things to run an external command:

- Kernel.system "command"
- %x[command]
- `command`

So, in your case your Ruby code would probably be:

```
`java -jar <name of jar>.jar`
```

And it would work. It might be that you have to add the full path for Java here, but you might have to try that out yourself.